# mizzao:bootboxjs freeze my meteor app

Tags: bootbox, meteor

I'm triying tu use bootboxjs in my meteor app.

This is what I'm doing:

```
Template.test.events({
  'click #logo': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

   bootbox.alert("Hello world!")
  }
});
```

When I click on "#logo" all my screen become "darker", a bootbox appear with "Hello world!" and OK button but no focus is set.

When I click on the OK button or outside the bootbox, nothing happens. My app is frozen.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thx

Comment: I've used mizzao:bootboxjs before and it works fine for me, you should update your question with some more info on what your current setup is.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was a bootstrap CSS file conflict.

I had an old version of bootstrap in my project.

Removing the old css solved this situation.